# More efficient code for using operators

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello again fellow programmers

Table `Customer`

```
cust_nbr
cust_name
cust_street_address
Cust_City
Cust_Zip
Cust_industry_code
```

I am trying to select:  customer number, customer name, customer zip & customer industry code for all those customers who have industry code between 1000 and 2000 or more than 5000 and then sorting the output by industry code.

here is my attempt:

```
select CUST_NBR, CUST_NAME,CUST_ZIP, CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE 
  from customer 
 where CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE between 1000 and 2000 
    or CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE>5000 
 order by CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE ;
```

do you see any issues with it? Someone mentioned there is a minor issue but i can't spot it as it seems to be giving me what i need.

Thanking you kindly.

Comment: Why would they tell you there's a minor issue but not what it was?

Comment: I just add that BETWEEN is a bit confusing operator. As you see, your first condition implies `CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE >= 1000 and CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE <= 2000`. I am pretty sure this what you wanted. However, one may assume that you have made a mistake, that you instead wanted something like `CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE > 1000 and CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE < 2000`. In fact, your next condition uses `CUST_INDUSTRY_CODE>5000`, which makes me think: what if you actually wanted < for the first one???

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cust_nbr,
cust_name,
cust_zip,
cust_industry_code
FROM customer
WHERE 
    (cust_industry_code >= 1000 AND cust_industry_code <= 2000) 
    OR cust_industry_code > 5000
ORDER BY cust_industry_code;
```

You may use a BETWEEN statement if you prefer. The parenthesis are required if you use the greater than equals version here. I recommend them regardless to communicate your intent to people that view this code later.

It is more typical to capitalize the SQL commands and use lower case for your columns, but that is just a stylistic point. It will work either way.